# Pie chart is over lapping the values when there is nill values present in hash table powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

Partition in pie chart is overlapping when there is nill value present for particular portion , I tried my level best to overcome this problem. I had attached image how it is appearing.

```
# Keeping my data for chart 
$pass=10 
$fail=0
$skip=0
$DataArray = @{ pass=$pass;Fail=$fail; Skip=$skip }

# create chart object
$Chart = New-object System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart
$Chart.Width = 400
$Chart.Height = 400
$Chart.Left = 20
$Chart.Top = 20

# chart colour palette (must match data array order)
$chart.Palette = [System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartColorPalette]::None
$Chart.PaletteCustomColors = @( [System.Drawing.Color]::Yellow,  [System.Drawing.Color]::Green, [System.Drawing.Color]::Red )

# create a chartarea to draw on and add to chart
$ChartArea = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea
$Chart.ChartAreas.Add($ChartArea)
# add data to chart
[void]$Chart.Series.Add("Data")
$Chart.Series["Data"].Points.DataBindXY($DataArray.Keys, $DataArray.Values)
$chart.Series["Data"].ChartType = "Pie"
$Chart.Series["Data"]["PieLabelStyle"] = "Outside"
$Chart.Series["Data"]["PieLineColor"] = "Black"
($Chart.Series["Data"].Points.FindMaxByValue())["Exploded"] = $true
#$Chart.Series["Data"][?PieLabelStyle?] = ?Disabled?

# Legend
$Legend = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Legend
$Legend.IsEquallySpacedItems = $True
$Legend.BorderColor = 'Black'
$Chart.Legends.Add($Legend)
$chart.Series["Data"].LegendText = "#VALX (#VALY)"

# save chart to file
$Chart.SaveImage("c:\Temp\piechart2.png", "PNG")
```

[image: How image is appearing available here]

EDITED :- Here is the solution for my problem. Just added below line to code that automatically controlled the labels on the pie chart

$Chart.Series["Data"]['PieLabelStyle'] = 'Disabled'